# Storing and using Windows Handle ( WId ) in registry

Tags: c++, qt, window-handles

I wish to store the Window handle of a running instance of an application in the registry, the WId of a widget ( in Qt ).

I need this to ensure that if another application starts, it can check the registry to know whom it is supposed to send a message to, using sendMessage() windows API.

How do I achieve this?

The type of a Windows handle , HWND, of which **WId is a typedef**..is a void pointer.

How do I store information of this type in a registry setting, and then retrieve to use it again?

Please help me with this.
I’ll be obliged. Thanks.

Comment: `FindWindow()` API can give you the window handle whenever you want. You don't need to store a handle in registry.

Comment: The application which requires the Handle is like the second instance of the application. Looking at `FindWwindow()` ,  it uses the className and WindowName as parameters, so..isn't there some sort of ambiguity in prospect..? As two instances of the same application, with the same class name etc. are running. Kindly advise on this. And the parameters of `FIndMessage()` if I've understood them wrong...

Comment: Sounds like a bad design. The registry is for persistent information and the window handle is the exact opposite. Shared memory would be a more appropriate mechanism, or a named pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the bitness of the your program you can either use `REG_DWORD` for 32-bit programs or `REG_QWORD` for 64-bit programs.

Comment: Conversions to and from QString for REG_DWORD and REG_QWORD?

Comment: `QString::toULong` will do QString to REG_DWORD. `QString::toULongLong` will do QString to REG_QWORD.